# how do I mock a dependency of a service in my angular unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I'm using karma, angular and mocha.

The `MyServices` module I want to inject. It's `addThing` method also calls a `$localStorage` provider and I want to test that the `$localStorage.setItem` method has been implicitly called when I call `MyServices.addThing(data)`

Here's my code:

```
describe('MyServices', function() {
  var $q;
  var $rootScope;
  var $scope;
  var MyServices;
  var $timeout;
  var $httpBackend;

  // inject modules
  beforeEach(function(){
    module('my.stuff');

    var _LocalStorage_ = {
      setItem: function(){
        return 'foo';
      }
    };

    // mock the dependencies of the module we are testing
    module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('$localStorage', _LocalStorage_); //here is where the error occurs
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_, _MyServices_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    MyServices = _MyServices_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  it.only('should call a method and access localStorage', function(){
    var spyAdd = sinon.spy(MyServices, 'addThing');
    var spySetItem = sinon.spy($localStorage, 'setItem');

    MyServices.addThing({ name: 'Thing' });

    expect(spyAdd.callCount).to.equal(1);
    expect(spySetItem.callCount).to.equal(1);
  })
});
```

When I run it I get an error that `$localStorage` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have register that fake $localStorage, just use the original one and create a spy on the setItem method.

so remove this

```
var _LocalStorage_ = {
  setItem: function(){
    return 'foo';
  }
};
module(function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('$localStorage', _LocalStorage_); //here is where the error occurs
});
```

but inject it here

```
var $localStorage;
beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_, _MyServices_, _$httpBackend_, _$localStorage_) {
  $q = _$q_;
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  $timeout = _$timeout_;
  MyServices = _MyServices_;
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  $localStorage = _$localStorage_; //here
}));
```

since you have already created a spy on the method, so nothing needs to be changed in the test.

Comment: its not available for injection because its in a different namespace than the MyServices injection. If I load the namespace its in, i'll have to mock like 100 things. So I wanted to just fake its existence using `$provide.value('$localStorage', myMock)`

Comment: what do you mean by different namespace, as in different modules?, anyway, just try $provide.factory in stead of $provide.value.

Comment: I tried `$provide.factory` it says its not a $get function.

Comment: The 2nd parameter should be a function not an object if you use .factory. $provide.factory('$localStorage', function(){return _LocalStorage_;});

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare *LocalStorage* outside of your beforeEach.  Btw, you don't need the _, you can just call it LocalStorage.

I also recommend downloading [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/) because it has a bunch of useful methods when spying or mocking dependencies.